# What does the summation in the 2nd term mean? Is the notation correct? (see the picture)

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I specifically do not understand the i<j below the summation.

[Here is the application of the formula i am struggling with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAQve.png)
$$\sum_{i=1}^{j}p_i^{4}+\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}\sum_{i<j}^{j-1}(2p_ip_j)^{2}$$
where pi and pj are the frequencies of the ith and jth alleles and i= 1, 2, 3, ... , j

This is the paper with the original Formula https://sci-hub.st/10.1111/j.1095-8312.1999.tb01157.x

This is the Formula by extracted from D. PAETKAU  & C. STROBECK (1994) https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-294X.1994.tb00127.x

$$\sum_{i}^{}p_i^{4}+\sum_{i}^{}\sum_{j>i}^{}(2p_ip_j)^{2}$$

Comment: It seems like there is an extra summation sign, as if the author intended to replace one by the other (they mean the same thing) and accidentally left both in.  If you look at equation $(1)$ in the paper, it only has two summation signs, not three.

Comment: The notation for the indices looks wrong.  j is used as a summation index and and as an upper limit on itself.